# Is there keyboard navigation of questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request, navigation

Is there a way to navigate the questions and answers via the keyboard?  I'm thinking of something like what gmail does.

I'd rather not depend on a Greasemonkey script if I have to.

Comment: Do you mean in a similar manner to Google Reader, and Gmail?

Comment: Either one actually since they are similar in their core navigation via keyboard.  j/k to go down/up the questions, o to open, r to answer/reply, c to comment...and then j/k to go down/up the answers on a question page.  s to star/favorite it.  uhm...+/- to up/down vote?

Comment: Would really like to see this.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts for next/previous answer would be extremely helpful for a question with a lot of answers. See http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/users/reviews/reviewing-diffs/#keyboard-shortcuts for an over-the-board (but still helpful) example.

Comment: This [has been requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-stack-overflow) in a question with a surprisingly similar ID.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen any real method of keyboard navigation outside of your standard keyboard navigation for the web browser, and this has a tendency to skip over some things like the vote mechanisms and other AJAX-esque elements.