# A hidden-undocumented SE keyboard shortcut for searching

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts

While I answered this question in Stack Overflow:
[How does the Stack Overflow Search Input work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11133206/601179)

I found this hidden feature: If you type your search expression than clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will open a new tab\window with the results for your search expression.

I thought it will make someone happy, so I shared the info.

**Update:**

For some  browsers you will need to allow popups in the site to make it work.

---

For the sake of completness The keydown (`javascript` - jQuery)code looks like this:

```
function(c) {
    if (13 == c.which && c.ctrlKey && d.val()) 
        return window.open("/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(d.val()), "_newtab"), !1
}​
```

<sub>(Maybe it should be in an answer using the  *"share your knowledge, Q&A-style"* feature?)</sub>

Comment: Should I make it a Q&A style? it's not like it can be answered...

Comment: `clicking Ctrl + Enter` ... ... ...

Comment: No repro here on FF12...or did you mean that you can use that as userscript?

Comment: @UristMcBobby. Write some text in the little search text on the top right screen, than click Ctrl + Enter. Did it work?

Comment: No...`Ctrl+Enter` does nothing for me.

Comment: I have to allow a popup for it to work in Firefox 13, but once I do, it does open in a new tab.

Comment: @UristMcBobby. Maybe you blocked popups? I tried it in IE and removing this restriction seems to do the magic.

Comment: @pythonscript. 19 secs later.

Comment: @gdoron: Ohh...true...

Comment: @UristMcBobby. It's funny, SE programmers write features, sharing no one about them. I'm sure even they didn't know about it... Well that's why we have SO. `:)`

Comment: Perhaps this should just be answer to [Hidden features of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/148672)