# Keyboard Shortcuts in SE Chat

Tags: support, chat

The [Stack Exchange chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) should be updated with some documentation on what keyboard shortcuts are available. e.g.:

- Typing `@<startofname>-<tab>` starts an autocomplete of people's names (***update*** actually is in the FAQ)..
- Up-arrow to edit last chat message (***update*** actually is in the FAQ)
- escape to clear any notifications, (or cancel editing, etc.) (***update*** actually is in the FAQ).

Is there a list of these features somewhere? Which ones are missing?

(I could not find one....).

**EDIT:** as has been so politely pointed out in the comments.... some of these are mentioned in the FAQ (OK, all of them...).

Modified request: Can there be a section added to the FAQ which lists these features in an easy to find way (instead of having to read the whole thing to locate a small piece of information....)?

Comment: "↑ up arrow to edit" is part of the "How do I talk" section

Comment: "ESC" to clear the indicator, and auto-complete are both in the "How do I know when someone is talking?" section

Comment: Right. Click that [show more] button ;)

Comment: Here's another one: hit Ctrl+Enter to open search results in a new tab when entering terms into the search field in the top bar. See "[A hidden-undocumented SE keyboard shortcut for searching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137117/246931)".

Answer (score 8):

Community Wiki Answer:

**Entering text:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> --> Format the text 'Fixed Font'
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> --> Cancel editing the text
- Markdown formatting is slightly different than in regular comments:

  - `---strikethrough text---`
- Automagic links:

  - `[tag:tag-speak]` renders a tag link (whether that tag exists or not)
  - `[help/on-topic]` renders as a "Help Center" link to the "how to ask" page
  - `[badge:badge-name]` renders as `[badge:badge-name]`, but it's *so much more better* than just `badge-name`.

**Addressing people:**

To address someone called `john-doe` use:

- `@j`-<kbd>Tab</kbd> --> Start typing the name, and tab to autocomplete (escape to cancel autocomplete)
- `@joh` would be enough to ping that user, since only the first 3 letters are required (particularly useful when chatting from a mobile)

To reply to any post (yes, *including your own*!), prefix your message with the post ID. e.g. to reply to post #12345678 you'd say:

```
:12345678 *(message text here)*
```

You can get the post ID by hovering the message in question; that will reveal a drop-down menu on its left edge - hover the dropdown menu and your browser should pick up a url like (for post #12345678): `chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12345678#12345678`.

**Editing previous messages:**

- <kbd>↑</kbd> -> go back in editable messages

***"While You Where Away"* Notifications:**

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> - clear all notifications
- adding a new message clears them too.
- click on the notifications to visit the oldest one (which will clear just that oldest item)

**Searching:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> when searching to open search results in a new tab