# Please add keyboard shortcuts on question pages

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

[Keyboard shortcuts, phase one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one) seems a bit dead and seemed more navigate-y in nature.

I'd like a few things in particular on question pages:

- Edit a question
- Close a question
- Retag a question

Or do these things already exist and I don't know about them? This happens a lot. I suspect I could also do this myself locally with JavaScript but I can't be the only one that edits a lot.

Only somewhat related, but it might be nice to hook up an SO-standardized code formatter to make my life even easier. I know this has been discussed before, but it'd be pretty  handy.

*(As long as the braces go in the right place, at the end of the line ;)*

Comment: Putting braces on a new line should be a bannable offense.