# Proposed tweak to comment UI for long threads

Tags: discussion, comments, user-interface

I've been working with [Stéphane](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/246949/st%C3%A9phane-martin) on some slight changes to the way we display comment-related elements on posts with long comment threads. There are a few problems we're trying to solve:

1. It's not very obvious when comments are hidden, which could lead to a user missing out on important context or other information about the post.
2. When there are hidden comments, we have a single button to accomplish two tasks: add a comment, and show hidden comments. We've toyed with doing a bigger overhaul on comment UI, but it's difficult right now for us to have a sense of what users are intending to do with comments. Splitting these two actions into two separate buttons will help us get a better understanding of user behavior, and be less confusing to the user. (**If you click "add a comment" in the new version, it will still expand any hidden comments**; we still want you to read what's there before posting your own thoughts :) )
3. Single-line comments take up two lines, which leads to more scrolling / fewer posts visible above the fold. This is particularly problematic for comments on questions – the more space comments take up, the farther down the first answer gets pushed, and most people viewing a question page are there to find an answer.

## Proposal

> [image: add / show comments split]

---

## Current Version, for comparison

> [image: current add/show comments combined]

## The key changes:

- There's a new double-lined horizontal rule between the last comment and the add / show buttons. We hope this draws a bit more attention to the fact that there are comments hidden, without overemphasizing the comment area as a whole.
- "Add a comment" and "show N more comments" are two different buttons, but close together so you notice them both. "Add a comment" is the more likely desired action, so it's a bit more eye-catching.
- Single-line comments will now take up only a single line. Rather than having the upvote arrow and flag icon stacked vertically, they'll be shown horizontally on hover.

What do you think?

Comment: @VotetoClose If you click "add a comment", it'll still expand hidden comments. I bolded that part in the post so it would stick out a little more.

Comment: What's the reason for doing the button + text link thing instead of just |-separated links as on posts?

Comment: Also, how is voting/flagging gonna work on mobile, where hover is a bit infuriating? Already pretty easy to hit the wrong thing there.

Comment: The double line seems like too much separation - as though it has little to do with the comments above.

I like the separate actions, though, often I want to see the comments but don't want the interruption of a big comment box that I wasn't planning on using.

Comment: @Shog9 The app does this well - tapping a comment brings up the options for flagging, voting, editing, etc. In the web interface, however, you're right.  I always tap the comment, then pinch-zoom in on the flagging icons to make sure I hit the right one.  Definitely not mobile browser friendly.

Comment: @Shog9 1) We already have quite a few |-separated items (note that the | doesn't appear on all sites anyway); the comment stuff neither belongs up with those other items nor warrants repetition of the same style; on a text-heavy page, all of those links are already starting to blend together. 2) I don't know how this will work on mobile, since we haven't finalized the desktop version yet. :)

Comment: @Laura *"I don't know how this will work on mobile, since we haven't finalized the desktop version yet."* Might be worth taking both into account during the design phase, rather than relegating the mobile UI to an afterthought once the desktop UI is finalized...

Comment: @AdamDavis There's already [a separate project to revamp the mobile site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher); I just haven't connected with them yet to see if they already have plans for any changes to comments. We generally design for desktop first, then make adjustments for mobile – or, sometimes, punt on any mobile changes because it's a rarely-used-on-mobile feature. We haven't always done the greatest job with our mobile site, but we're trying to be better.

Comment: When you hover over a comment with upvotes, is the vote count _replaced_ by the flag and arrow? If so, could you expand on why?

Comment: I'm glad this comment section is getting long enough to demonstrate the eventual new format.

Comment: @JonEricson Yes, hovering means the comment score is replaced by flag and arrow. Our existing UI has taught users that hovering over comments reveals other actions; we decided to prioritize single-line comments only taking up one line, and this was the best way to do it. We aren't hiding any essential information here. By the time you hover, you've already seen the comment score, and if you forget it and really want to know, you just have to move your mouse off the comment.

Comment: This is `[status-completed]`, right?

Comment: @slhck Sort of. We split the "add / show x more comments" button into two separate actions, but there are a couple more subtler changes coming. status-in-progress :)

Comment: Speaking as a tablet user who no longer needs to hide my keyboard every time I expand a set of comments, **THANK YOU**

Comment: Personally, I hate this change. I have to spend a little extra effort now to figure out which link to click (to make sure I don't click the wrong one), while before there was only one link to click, so that wasn't a problem. Granted, though, I don't use a tablet for my Stack Exchanging.

Comment: I think it's a great change. I would add the triple dot ellipsis as @AdamDavis proposed in that bottom area to make it clearer that 'stuff is hidden' too.

Comment: Should it be possible to add a comment without having seen ALL the comments first?

Comment: @IanRingrose the only time you should be able to submit a comment without all the other comments expanded is if a new comment appears via realtime *while you are typing in the comment field.* If you experience something different, would you please start a new post describing the behavior and tag it as a bug?

Answer (score 82):

For particularly long comment threads I kinda want to know where the invisible comments are before clicking the "show all comments" and, frankly, I often don't want to re-read all the comments when I'm following up on a topic, just recent/new comments.

So I'd go a little further and propose that you put ellipses between comments where there are hidden comments, both to reinforce the position of the shown comments in the comment hierarchy, and so you can expand just a section or two of hidden comments, rather than the whole thing:

[image]

Probably make them the same gray used for the buttons/actions below.  It would immediately alert readers that some comments are hidden, and clicking on one set of ellipses would expand that section alone, giving users a greater degree of control over their reading.

While I'd be tempted to replace the ellipses with more information, "2 comments hidden by splattne and Jon Skeet"<sup>*</sup> I'd resist that temptation - the point of hiding them is to avoid information overload and provide ease of use for the most important comments.

Of course I'd still suggest expanding all when adding a comment, and the shortcut to expand all would probably still be used more.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Jon Skeet here used as an example.  In practice, Jon Skeet's comments are never hidden.</sub>

Comment: ***I kinda want to know where the invisible comments are before clicking the "show all comments"***. + 100. Your solution is *much* better at demonstrating this. Far too often I've read long comment chains and only realised at the bottom that I've missed `n` comments, and now the whole conversation reads entirely differently.

Comment: I'd like that feature, but I would go with a much more subtle indicator like a doubled line. The dots take up quite a bit of space.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm torn.  For those that know, a much thicker line would be sufficient.  The ellipses are very obvious and would be obvious for even those not familiar with our UI hints. We don't use a double-line or very thick line elsewhere to indicate more content. The mockup I made was done in paint.net quickly - I'd be happy with a much smaller amount of space being taken - have the lines butt up next to the ellipses, and take up only an extra 3-5 pixels rather than the 8-10 I've used.

Comment: I do like this feature, and had started off with a similar idea, but it turns out that calculating *where* the hidden comments are is much more expensive than calculating that there *are* hidden comments. For the sake of performance / page load times, we opted not to go that route.

Comment: I bet there's a solution to that which won't affect performance very much. There's this cool website where you can ask such questions to find out solutions you might not have considered...

Comment: @Laura Please move the "Show all comments" button to the top if you're not going to use this solution

Comment: @Laura seconded Gus's point - I'd like to know up-front if there are any gaps in context. Perhaps you can show: "Some comments hidden. Click to expand." at the _top_ of the chain. Of course, I prefer Adam's original proposal if at all possible.

Comment: @Laura: Another suggested idea similar to this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265347/visual-hint-for-the-location-of-hidden-comments?cb=1

Comment: Count me in too; http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270396/show-n-more-comments-usability-problem

Answer (score 28):

Rather than "Show x more comments" please consider "Show all y comments".

A lot of dynamic web pages now use "Show x more items", but don't mean to show you all items, merely more than you're currently viewing.

"Show all y comments" is much more clear about the purpose of that link.

Comment: Fair enough, and makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

Thoughts so far:

- **Separate actions** should prove interesting in terms of how folks actually interact with the UI, but I'm concerned that the inconsistent styling will skew the results here; that button sticks out a lot more than the link does. From a practical standpoint, an option that expands comments *without opening the form* would be really nice on mobile, where currently expanding the comments also opens (and puts focus in) the entry form, thus opening the keyboard and making it harder to *read* the comments you've just expanded!

  Interestingly, the mobile *app* already has two separate actions for expanding and commenting:

  [image: 1 more comment... Add Comment]

  Note that it also makes "add" a button and "expand" a link, but *puts the link first* - I tend to like this more, but whether or not this serves to influence interaction, I would recommend following this *style* purely for consistency's sake.
- **Collapsed voting buttons** are nice in terms of saving vertical space; my only concern here is that it may become even easier to hit the wrong button (especially on mobile, but this has been an occasional issue even on the desktop). No way to know until we see it in action; just something to be aware of.

  [As Adam notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235255/proposed-tweak-to-comment-ui-for-long-threads#comment773522_235255), aping the mobile app here might be a good solution *for the mobile site*; I tend to think this is overkill for the desktop though.

Comment: I'm not an UX expert and don't want to start a religious debate on it but most call to actions are located near the right bottom. In your given sample you could argue that for consistency's sake the App should follow the style on the sites.

Comment: @rene *"don't want to start a religious debate"* Well that's no fun.

Comment: That screenshot makes me feel sick... inconsistent from the real site :) Also, looking through the mockups with the button, I knew right away I would hesitate as to which button to click. The current way looks good and does what you need it to do.

Comment: has this change been deployed network wide? I ask because I started observing ["top n comments shown" limitation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-top-n-shown/ "implemented in 2009 for Stack Overflow") at sites that haven't had it so far - Workplace and Programmers

Comment: That's been the behavior on all sites for years, @gnat.  The difference for TWP and Progse is that for questions with > 15 answers, *all* comments are hidden by default - the top N are only shown if there are N comments with upvotes.

Answer (score -9):

What about such design instead?

> [image]

- Fixed height for the comments container, even when there are 100 comments
- "add comment" still always visible

Comment: Then either the comments are not in order, or the highest voted comments aren't on top and visible without taking action (like scrolling).  So I wouldn't prefer this method.

Comment: Eugh no. When looking at a large comment stream, scrolling up and down that small area will ***not*** be fun.

Comment: So 2 or 3 +0 comments will obscure a +100 comment posted right after them?

Comment: @Doorknob well, the sort can be changed.

Comment: ... then reading the comment thread wouldn't even make any sense, since you would see replies to comments before the comments themselves. (And clicking `sort` -> `newest` is definitely not easier than one click of `show all comments`.)

Comment: Good point @Doorknob, guess I didn't put enough thought into this! :-(

Comment: Meh, inframes are bound to cause problems with scrolling. When reading a long comment thread I don't want a small window, and even more than that, when scrolling that small window I don't want to accidentally scroll the outer page every second time because my mouse focus is at the wrong place.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thanks, but I really don't mind the downvotes and accept them as what they are - people who disagree/don't like my idea.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens well, obviously we have very different opinions, and our only option is to "agree to disagree" about downvotes - and for what it's worth, I usually leave a comment when downvoting, knowing it can sometimes get me in trouble as with Iain.

Comment: 1 more comment (I'm in a rush): now THAT are the kind of downvoter that "I" like... those are the friends that dare to say "hey, there is some spinach between your teeth"!