# What is the order of comments for each post in all StackExchange communities?

Tags: feature-request, comments, sorting

I focused on the order of comments in SO, but I can't figure out a specific rule. If you look carefully, you see a interesting order for comments. The order depends on both comment's votes and comment's ids. Now I want to know, what is that combination? Does anybody know?

Maybe it is something like this:

```
ORDER BY (timestamp)+(total_vote*100)
```

**Columns:**

- `timestamp`  : Stores the time which comment has been entered.
- `total_vote` : Stores the number of total votes for each comment.

Comment: what do you mean order? The order they're displayed in under the post?

Comment: @Shog9 Yes exactly.

Comment: It's *always* timestamp.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't think so, because if sixth comment (which have to be hide in first) get a vote, then it will be show (I mean is behind "show more comment")

Comment: Yes, but the comments shown will still be in chronological order.

Comment: When there are lots of comments, the system automatically hides comments with no or few upvotes. When you click "show more", it places all of the hidden comments back where they would have been chronologically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the same for all sites. What varies is the definition of a lot of comments.

- if there are not a lot of comments, they are in time order
- if there are a lot of comments, those with no upvotes are hidden. The unhidden ones are still in time order

More details: [Proposed tweak to comment UI for long threads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235255/proposed-tweak-to-comment-ui-for-long-threads)

Comment: Ah, alright then ..! +1