# What did I type to cause gray background in question?

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes I'll be navigating within a question, probably typing a comment, the question will get highlighted with a gray background, like this:

[image]

I guess I must have typed a keyboard shortcut, but I don't know what it is. What does this shading mean, and what did I type to cause it?

The only way I've found to undo it is to reload the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably hit <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>, which are [the keyboard shortcuts for navigating up and down by post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102774/341145). If you go to a post with many answers, and tap <kbd>j</kbd> several times in a row, you'll navigate through the answers down the page.

The currently selected post is highlighted in grey shadow.

Comment: That seems to be it. Is there an unselect shortcut?

Comment: @Barmar Not that I know of, but I could be mistaken. (The help menu key is `?`, in case you need it!)

Comment: I just disabled the keyboard shortcuts, I never use them intentionally.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it.