# Is there a shortcut for replying to chat messages?

Tags: support, chat, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut for replying to messages, much like the up arrow is a shortcut for editing your previous message?

Comment: Related: ["Add Keyboard Shorcuts to Stack Overflow"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-stack-overflow), currently marked as "Status-Planned".  Bear in mind this question was asked long before chat existed, so maybe when shortcuts come into play Chat will be involved too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not built-in to the chat system, but [SEChatModifications](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts) adds the capability. You hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> until you've selected the message you want; in this screenshot I hit it three times:

[image: Screenshot]

Then you can hit miscellaneous keys to perform different actions on that message; <kbd>r</kbd> replies

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome users who can't install the tool in Michael's answer, there is *something* in the Chrome Store, but it's not nearly as cool.

[SE Chat Reply Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chat-reply-helper-for-sta/edjeilghaflgcdjdldnkdihoaigdhibd?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Comment: Chrome supports userscripts natively; I use it on Chrome. You might need [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) to install a script outside of the official store though

Comment: Works like a charm. Most awesome @MichaelMrozek. Thanks.