# Can we get a link to our network profile in the profile popup?

Tags: feature-request, network-profile

This may seem like a minor usability issue, but as the number of Stack Exchange sites continues to grow, I think that this will become more and more helpful.

I'd like to have a one-click method (in addition to the *two-click* method from my profile page) to visit my network profile from any Stack Exchange site. Could we get a link to our network profiles in the profile popup?

For example:

[image: Sample profile popup with a "network profile" link]

Comment: It's only a 2-click process as it is right now.  Click your name in the header to go to your site specific profile, click Network Profile under your gravatar.

Comment: @squillman Yeah, I know. I'm just a stickler for conserving mouse clicks whenever I can.

Comment: Then maybe you'd like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23472/131541

Comment: Maybe the accounts tab specifically instead of just the network profile?

Comment: @agf That would probably be helpful, as well, but I'd rather keep the behavior of the **network profile** link consistent for now.